# Smtp relay service recommendation to increase deliverability

Tags: smtp

I need a recommendation for a email relay service to use on multiple domains with C#.

I don't want to worry about blacklisting and am looking for increase deliverability on confirmation emails etc.

Currently, trialling SocketLabs (https://www.socketlabs.com/od/signup) which works perfectly but limits you too 500 email/month. I don't mind paying but the starting level is 10,000 email @$39 which for me is overkill. I probably need to send 2000 max a month.

Does anyone have any recommendation or views on: http://www.jangosmtp.com/Pricing.asp or http://www.smtp.com/?gclid=CPDr5qjruaUCFYVO4QodUhzUBA

Comment: There's no such thing as increased deliverability. If the recipient server or mailbox is unavailable it doesn't matter how many servers try to send the email, they'll all fail.

Comment: But as I said one of the main concerns I have is to not have to worry about whitelisting with isp's etc of my mail servers I'd rather let the professional handle that.

Comment: Down vote? ok. Well atleast theres a sensible accepted answer below

Comment: @joeqwerty you may wish to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques As I state in the question I'd rather leave experts to deal with conforming to email sending standards and simply wanted a service recommendation.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some well-known alternatives are [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/), [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) and [AuthSMTP](http://www.authsmtp.com/). I've no experience with any of them.

Comment: I've used AuthSMTP in the past, can recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just send mail out directly?

- make sure you have reverse DNS setup
- make sure it's not an open relay
- setup SPF records
- look into DKIM (I've never needed this to be honest)
- make sure your content isn't "spammy"

Comment: I dont own the server and cant control whether reverse dns etc is setup or not

Comment: Reverse DNS is something you'd request from your service provider (or whomever owns the block of IPs that your static IP resides with).